# getting null pointer exception on using savedInstanceState.getInt( "Phase", 1 );?

Tags: android

I'm getting null pointer exception on this line inside OnCreate function:

```
int Phase = savedInstanceState.getInt( "Phase", 1 );
```

According to what I read, this function should return the value associated with "Phase" or 1 if no mapping exits for the key "Phase". However for some reason I'm getting this exception, any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your savedInstanceState object is `null`. It will not be null if your activity or fragment is being recreated from a layout change, for example.

Try using:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
  Phase = savedInstanceState.getInt( "Phase", 1 );
} else {
  Phase = ...some other meaningful value...
}
```

Comment: I thought that the system itself would pass a non-null Bundle to OnCreate when the activity is created `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: It is always `null` the first time onCreate is called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you are getting is not because of a missing key but because the variable  `savedInstanceState` is null. Have you checked that?